# event.touchesForView().AnyObject() not working in Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitouch, uievent

This worked perfectly before:

```
func doSomethingOnDrag(sender: UIButton, event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = event.touchesForView(sender).AnyObject() as UITouch
    let location = touch.locationInView(sender)
}
```

But in Xcode 6.3, I now get the error:

> Cannot invoke 'AnyObject' with no arguments

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 1.2, `touchesForView` now returns a native Swift `Set` rather than an `NSSet`, and `Set` doesn't have an `anyObject()` method.

It does have a `first` method, which is much the same thing.  Note, also, that you won't be able to use `as?` any more, you'll have to cast it using `as?` and handle the nil possibility, here's one approach:

```
func doSomethingOnDrag(sender: UIButton, event: UIEvent) {
    if let touch = event.touchesForView(sender)?.first as? UITouch,
           location = touch.locationInView(sender) {
            // use location
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func doSomethingOnDrag(sender: UIButton, event: UIEvent) {
    let buttonView = sender as! UIView;
    let touches : Set<UITouch> = event.touchesForView(buttonView)!
    let touch = touches.first!
    let location = touch.locationInView(buttonView)
}
```