# 'Set' <NSObject> does not have a member named 'anyObject'

Tags: swift, object, member, named

today i updated xcode with Swift 1.2 my code was working well on Swift 1.1 but when i updated i got this error:

> 'Set'  does not have a member named 'anyObject'

Here's my code:

```
override public func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let location:CGPoint? = touches.anyObject()?.locationInView(self)
    if let loc = location {
        if (!CGRectContainsPoint(ScaleRect(self.bounds, n: 2.0), loc)) {
            self.highlighted = false
        }
    }
}
```

Does you guys have an idea on how can i fix that please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771896/overriding-method-with-selector-touchesbeganwithevent-has-incompatible-type, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29566861/event-touchesforview-anyobject-not-working-in-xcode-6-3, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593411/swift-1-2-replacement-for-nsset-anyobject

Answer (score 33):

Use `first` which is the equivalent of anyObject of NSSet for Swift sets:

```
touches.first
```

Comment: *"Set - does not have an equivalent of NSSet anyObject method"* – What about `first` ?